Matrix with elementary symmetric polynomials as entries
Let $n\geq 1$, and for each $j=1,\ldots, n+1$ let $\mathbf{X}_{j}=(X_{j1},\ldots, X_{jn})$ be $n$ variables. Let $M$ be the $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $$M_{ij}=(-1)^i e_{i-1}(\mathbf{X}_j),$$ where $e_{i-1}(\mathbf{X}_j)$ is the $(i-1)$-th symmetric polynomial on variables $\mathbf{X}_j$, i.e. $e_{i}(\mathbf{X}_j) = \sum_{1\leq k_1 < \ldots < k_{i}\leq n} X_{k_1} \cdots X_{k_{i}}$ when $i\geq 1$ and $e_0(\mathbf{X}_j) = 1$.
Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field and let $H$ be a multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{F}\setminus \{0\}$. What is an as-sharp-as-possible upper bound for the number of distinct $n+1$ subsets $S_1,\ldots, S_{n+1}$ of $H$, each of size $n$, so that $M$ has zero determinant after replacing each tuple of variables $\mathbf{X}_j$ by $S_{j}$ (using any ordering of $S_{j}$), for $j=1,\ldots, n+1$?
(In general I would appreciate any insight on sufficient or necessary conditions for sets $S_1,\ldots, S_{n+1}$ making $M$ have nonzero determinant after replacing $\mathbf{X}_j$ by $S_j$ for all $j$)

@PeterTaylor You are right. I reformulated the question, thanks
